# mypy seems to require type annotations on __init__ methods only sometimes?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

In a reasonably large project, I'm seeing mypy complain about un-annotated init methods only in some cases.

For example, here are 2 classes in the same file:

```
from typing import Dict

class PostgresConnector:
    """Abstract BaseConnector class containing the methods to interact with your configured connection."""

    def __init__(self, key: str, uri: str): 
        pass

class Connections:
    """Temporary container for connections. This will be replaced."""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.connections: Dict[str, PostgresConnector] = {}
```

checking these with mypy gives me an error only on the *second* class declaration:

```
src/app/task/task_resources.py:50: error: Function is missing a return type annotation  [no-untyped-def] (this is the Connection __init__ declaration)
```

There are a number of places in the codebase where I've had to add a `->None` type annotation to the `__init__` method , but not all. Can anyone suggest any reasons for this inconsistent behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga which part is not fully annotated in the first case (I did not display the entire method, thought it was distracting). In any case it is the second class that's giving the mypy error.

Comment: I didn't notice that it was for `Connections`. In any casse, I cannot reproduce your error using `mypy --strict test.py` when I put that code in `test.py`. I get no errors, using `mypy 0.910`

Comment: A colleague of mine also add issues with `mypy` which I could not reproduce, although we were supposed to be using the same exact env. They just felt arbitrary. Hence, to narrow down the problem, it would certainly help if you could post all versions and packages in use (the relevant ones of course).

Comment: @deponovo mypy 0.812

Comment: Have you tried upgrading mypy?

Comment: Can't reproduce as well.